# R Dynamic Legend Labels with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have the following R code:

```
g <- plot_ly(df, x = ~Day) %>%
  add_trace(data=df[which(df$FcNum==1),], y = ~ProjAmount, name = ~paste(FcName), hoverinfo = "text", text = ~paste('Projected Amt: ', round(ProjAmount,2)), mode = 'lines', width = 1, connectgaps = "false") %>% 
  add_trace(data=df[which(df$FcNum==2),], y = ~ProjAmount, name = 'Forecast 2', hoverinfo = "text", text = ~paste('Projected Amt: ', round(ProjAmount,2)), mode = 'lines', width = 1, connectgaps = "false") %>%
        layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)
```

You may have noticed that in the first trace, for the name variable, I have entered `~paste(FcName)`. This is because what I am trying to do is get the name of the trace/line on the legend to be the value in the `FcName` column in my data frame.

My data frame looks something like this:

```
 Day       Amount    ProjAmt      FcNum    FcName
 1          10.4       55          1        userinputname1
 1          10.4       37          2        customuserinputname2
 2          22.1       55          1        userinputname1
 2          22.1       37          2        customuserinputname2
 3          43.5       55          1        userinputname1
 3          43.5       37          2        customuserinputname2
 4          24.1       55          1        userinputname1
 4          24.1       55          2        customuserinputname2
...         ...        ...
34          37.8       75          1        userinputname1
34          37.8       99          2        customuserinputname2
35          12.8       75          1        userinputname1
35          12.8       99          2        customuserinputname2
```

Where the `FcName` is the same for any given `FcNum`. So `FcNum == 2` will have the name `customeuserinputname2` throughout the data frame (however, the end user is able to change this name, meaning in the add_trace I can't just set the names variable equal to `customuserinputname2`). So for the first add_trace, because I filter the df to say `FcNum == 1`, that means the value in the FcName column will always be `userinputname1`

My question is (I believe) a somewhat simple one. Is there something I can enter in place of `~paste(FcName)` that will result in the name of the trace being set to the (first/last?) string value in the `FcName` column of the data frame?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. Do you mean that you want the first/last value regardless of whether FcNum == 1?

Comment: I think so (if I understand you correctly)... When the above table is filtered so that FcNum == 1, the FcName column will have the same value on each row. So in the first trace, which will always be set to FcNum == 1, I want the name of that trace to be the value in the FcName column, which as I just mentioned, will be the same value for each row.